# Unknown reason for shutdown after suspend

Tags: suspend, dell, power-management, shutdown, 23.04

I have a Dell Inspiron 16 Plus 7620 running Kubuntu 23.04.  It suspends as expected, but if the laptop lid is closed for a while the system powers off.  It should stay asleep but never does.

There's no BIOS setting that seems to affect this.  I've tried every setting of `HandleLidSwitch` in `logind.conf`. I also tried `IgnoreLid=true` in `UPower.conf`.

`journalctl` output below seems to indicate that it's not going through the normal shutdown process but the hardware is powering off after suspend.

```
May 13 17:29:37 matt-inspiron-16 systemd[1]: Reached target sleep.target - Sleep.
May 13 17:29:37 matt-inspiron-16 systemd[1]: Starting grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB...
May 13 17:29:37 matt-inspiron-16 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
May 13 17:29:37 matt-inspiron-16 systemd-sleep[33807]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
-- Boot 3f65a17e06fb4088b791e7224b42b75a --
May 14 08:13:27 matt-inspiron-16 kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x429, date = 2023-01-11
May 14 08:13:27 matt-inspiron-16 kernel: Linux version 6.2.0-20-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-035) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-17ubuntu1) 12.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.40) #20-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  6 07:48:48 UTC 2>
May 14 08:13:27 matt-inspiron-16 kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-20-generic root=UUID=6b865555-985f-4052-b452-813657be2501 ro quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0 vt.handoff=7
```

**How do I get the laptop to stay asleep and not power off when the lid is closed?**

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** You might want to review logs for errors as they might provide some clues regarding the current behavior. Run `sudo dmesg` to view activity after running `sudo systemctl suspend` to force you machine into suspend mode. Also, how long does your machine stay in suspend mode? I'm pretty sure that suspend state will power off if battery levels reach a min value.

Comment: @richbl `dmesg` is showing a lot of output. I see things like `Freezing user space processes`. What should I look for? Battery is not getting low at all so I'm certain it's not that.

Comment: You're looking for anything that's generating warnings/errors (likely ACPI or PM). I'd also suggest reviewing boot logs (`sudo journalctl -b`) after rebooting from a power off state induced by sleep. Please post both the `dmesg` and `journalctl` output (just the interesting bits) directly in your question. Finally, can you please define "for a while" (the time before your laptop powers off. Is it seconds, minutes, hours, days?